# How many cards does a player get for a card collection match in clan wars?

Tags: clash-royale

Players receive different numbers of cards for card collection matches when participating in clan wars. It varies by the player's clan's league, the player's trophy count, and whether the player won or lost.

What specific number of cards does a player get depending on the player's clan's league, the player's trophy count, and whether the player won or lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of cards you earn for a win is double what you get for a draw or a loss.  The following tables show you how many cards you will get based on your arena, your clan's league, and whether or not you won or lost.

Source: [Clash Royale Wikia](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars)

[image]

Comment: It appears that the cards gained on a loss or draw is just half what it it is for a win. Good find on the table.